# Java add new functions to library class

Tags: java, class, extend

The problem:
application uses some library. Like:

```
ClassA a=new ClassA();
```

In this library classA uses classB - e.g. call some method from classB.
I need to change how this method works.
Is it possible do without using AOP?
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to add more detail to your question.  It doesn't make sense as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

a) modify the source
b) modify the byte code

a) means: download the source, change it, build and use your own version. Drawback: for every new version of the library, you'll need to create a new  patched version

b) For this, AOP (probably using AspectJ) is the easiest way. Other options would be to do it programmatically using [commons / bcel](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) or [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/). AOP is easier because you only have to implement the behaviour you want, whereas using byte code manipulation, you would also have to do lots of infrastructure programming (e.g. providing a custom ClassLoader or Java Agent that runs your patch).

Alternative c) is often the best: contact the developer of the library and ask him to provide the functionality you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass ClassA if ClassA is not final.  You should probably download the source for the library and look at the internals to see how it works -- only create a subclass as a last resort -- you don't want to break the library.